# VScode in sync (i.e. automatically pulling) w/ all github repositories

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

How to have my VSCode reflecting company's GitHub repositories (i.e. production code is pulled in real-time from all repositories) at all times?

In other words, I just want to make sure that my VSCode **reflects production code at all times**, and my company has dozens of repositores.

Comment: Git doesn't automatically sync, so you'll need to have some way of doing this on a periodic basis (without doing it so often as to be abusive).  I suspect VS Code doesn't have that functionality built-in, so you may need o resort to pulling changes at the beginning of working on a particular repository.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much for your kind attention and patience. I'm from the business side of the company (but engineer undergrad and can read code) and I'm not savvy with these tools.

1) Can I write a script or something for this to be done at regular intervals?
2) And how can I pull 50 repositories from GitHub to VSCode at once?

My intention with these questions is: I just want to make sure that all the company's code is in VSCode and in sync with prod so I can read it anytime. 
Thank you. Wishing you a Happy New Year!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode is only fetching (not pulling) the repositories it detects in its workspace.

Meaning if you are just opening VSCode (no workspace), it would not fetch anything.

If you are opening VSCode with a repository folder (or multiple repository folders in one workspace), it would fetch each repository.

From there, you can see, for a given repository (depending on the current file you have opened), the branch, number of local commits ahead/behind compared to what is fetched. (as described in [issue 52339](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52339)):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1330321/41634668-6c3f71b2-7477-11e8-8eb2-f9a08f520170.png]

Depending on the branch currently checked-out, that would reflect "production" code.
It depends on how you manage "`production`" code: on master branch? On "`release`" branch.
Since VSCode is fetching *all* branches at regular interval, you would find your remote "production" branch (be it master or any other naming convention you are using) always up-to-date.

---

> 1. Can I write a script or something for this to be done at regular intervals?

You don't have to. VSCode already fetches regularly any remote Git repository it detects (if you have one opened)

> 2. And how can I pull 50 repositories from GitHub to VSCode at once?

You don't have to: as soon as you are opening any *one* of those 50 repositories, it will be automatically be refreshed (fetched), and you will see in the bottom left corner of VSCode if your local clone is up-to-date or not.
No need to do the same for the other 49 repos: as long as you are not working with them locally, you don't need to fetch from them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind attention. I wrote a comment above explaining the context. Wishing you a Happy New Year!

Comment: @DiF Thank you for your wishes. Happy New Year to you too, and your family. I have edited the answers to address your comment/context.

Comment: I've read the comments. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to get VS Code to pull or at least check and prompt for a pull on startup. I am constantly editing stale code because I forgot to pull. PULL, not FETCH.

Comment: @Marc Good question. I did not see an option for that (pull on start). You might need an extension, or a wrapper script which does a pull, before opening VSCode.